# Typescript generic to call object's method

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have such a class ("simplified"):

```
class MyDb {
    create(user: {name: string, id: number}) {
        // 
    }
    delete(id: number) {
        // 
    }
    read(id: number) {
        // 
    }
}
const db = new MyDb()
```

And I've got such a function:

```
function processRequest <Method extends keyof MyDb, Data extends Parameters<MyDb[Method]>> (
    method: Method,
    data: Data

) {
    db[method](data)  // here goes error. Argument of type 'number | { name: string; id: number; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ name: string; id: number; } & number'.
}
```

I've tried to play with  `Parameters<...>[0]` or `db[method](...data)` , but it doesn't help me.
Also, what's interesting for me is that my thought of generics was that the "type" would be inferred when I call that function, but in that situation it somehow breaks during writing.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=16&ssc=1&pln=23&pc=1#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)

Comment: If you encounter same problem inside class method - try using generic constraint on class level

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript can't really perform abstract reasoning with [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) [conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) like `Parameters<MyDb[K]>` inside of the body of `processRequest()` (since `K` or `Method` is a generic type parameter, and [the `Parameters` utility](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#parameterstype) is implemented with a conditional type.  Such types are essentially opaque to the type checker, and so in order to evaluate it, the type of `db[method]` is widened from the generic `MyDb[K]` to the [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of functions `MyDb[keyof MyDb]`.  And generally you can't safely call a union of functions unless you pass it an [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) of its arguments (see [the release notes for the introduction of support for calling a union of functions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-3.html#improved-behavior-for-calling-union-types)).  Basically the generic *correlation* between the type of `db[method]` and the type of `data` has been lost.

If you don't care about the compiler's ability to understand the correlation, you can just use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) and move on with your day:

```
(db[method] as (arg: typeof data) => void)(data); // okay
```

But if you want the compiler to follow your reasoning then the recommended approach, as described in [microsoft/TypeScript#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109), is to refactor your type operations so they are represented in terms of some "base" mapping type, generic [indexed accesses](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) into that base type, and [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) over that base type.  This will end up using equivalent types to what you have, but they will be represented in a way that lets the compiler "see" the intended relationship.

Here's one way to do it.  First, let's define the base type to be just the parameters to your `Db` methods.  This can be done programmatically:

```
type DbParams = { [K in keyof MyDb]: Parameters<MyDb[K]>[0] }        

/* type DbParams = {
    create: {
        name: string;
        id: number;
    };
    delete: number;
    read: number;
} */
```

Then `processRequest` can be written so that `data` is `DbParams[K]` directly:

```
function processRequest<K extends keyof MyDb>(
    method: K,
    data: DbParams[K]
) {
    const _db: { [P in keyof MyDb]: (arg: DbParams[P]) => void } = db;
    _db[method](data); // okay
}
```

Importantly, we've assigned `db` of type `Db` to a variable `_db` of the mapped type `{ [P in keyof MyDb]: (arg: DbParams[P]) => void }`.  This is equivalent to `Db`, but it's explicitly written as a mapped type over the base `DbParams` type.  The assignment succeeds because it's not actually generic (both `Db` and the mapped type are specific types that don't depend on `K`).

And now the call works.  The type of `_db[method]` is seen explicitly as `(arg: DbParams[K]) => void`.  That's a single call signature that accepts an argument of type `DbParams[P]`.  And since that's the exact type of `data`, the call `_db[method](data)` succeeds.

Again, the only difference between this version and your version is the representation of the types in terms of generic/mapped/indexed versions as described in microsoft/TypeScript#47109. It would be great if this weren't necessary, but for now this is the way you have to do it if you want to avoid type assertions or the like.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECyCeARARtA3gKGt6wBOApmAC4EAUArhAXgFzrQB2YAtgfRMXgJaMDmAGmjcAJvUYUWyGtAC+ASnRYcKgPSroy7LK3QRBEAVJlR4ydLyLMKtRt06VhMCJNim5mld23NKnToxieAAHAmgUAAUwPFYYAF4GAG0AaWFGaABrAngAewAzOCRkAF16KJi2UjwIAB4EFBTigD5EgAZiuQxVACpoINDw5HLY6ATrHHwiUnpxmyZWdmhOHn4Abm8cU3cpGnW-PZx9Q2ntiwPsJzcJHbx12Whu1QwMYBzGTj1UBMYCAHdClBkeTPDB5CiMYDEbhvaDBPA5YAEKAAJQIAEcKEjiK0aqkCAAPUiMEQwLK5Ar1ZBNMi6SoACxybmSAl0IhIYHokWisUaGC8KjIImQiXpjI6kGgZGifHo-QI+T07MUcSa0AAbjlRPJBUq7iCwRCoTC4QikRBURisbjoASiSTMtkFZTqbSjAymSyVGziBzBsMWBBefyJm8PgB9IUzaCJCJpB3kgElehSvAyv3cgMx4rK1Ua0RyUafc7QCPC0UiYo6n3yPXPE2IlHozGcMgAIkmJAIraEaGEbgArEJmGx6K2AIwAJgAzK25PIgA)

Comment: This can be easily extended to arbitrary number of params , thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
class MyDb {
    create(user: { name: string, id: number }) {
        // 
    }
    delete(id: number) {
        // 
    }
    read(id: number) {
        // 
    }
}

const db = new MyDb();

type MyDbKeys = keyof MyDb

// Conditional type that determines the type of the first argument of a method
type MethodArgs<T, M extends keyof T> = T[M] extends (...args: infer Parameters) => unknown ? Parameters[0] : never;

// Intermediate function for type safety
function callDbMethod<Method extends MyDbKeys >(method: Method, data: MethodArgs<MyDb, Method>) {
    return (db[method] as (...args: [MethodArgs<MyDb, Method>]) => void)(data);
}

function processRequest<Method extends MyDbKeys >(
    method: Method,
    data: MethodArgs<MyDb, Method>
) {
    callDbMethod(method, data);
}

// Usage
processRequest('create', { name: 'John', id: 1 });  // works
processRequest('delete', 1);                       // works
processRequest('read', 2);                         // works
```

I only added, callDbMethod for safetly calling the method. Your implementation could already get typed arguments. Trick is using **as** with **infinite typed a